# HTML5 Boilerplate Mobile not hiding 'Address Bar' mobile safari

Tags: web-applications, mobile-safari, html5boilerplate, meta, address-bar

I'm using thee latest awesome HTML boiler plate - [HTML 5 BOILERPLATE](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile)

Now if you open this link in mobile safari on iphone - [HTML 5 BOILERPLATE](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile) - once the page has fully loaded, the address bar slides up out the way.

Which is what should happen. But I downloaded the demo and started building my mobile app and I noticed it wasnt working for me, but I have carefully made sure everything is there that should make it work, but it still didn't

So I basically took the demo src files and made an exact duplicate of the [HTML 5 BOILERPLATE](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile) and put in on my server [HTML 5 BOLIERPLATE MYSERVER](http://motocomdigital.co.uk/development/html5/boilerplate/) for test.

It's pretty much an identical copy apart from I've loaded in the latest jQuery instead and have left font face out.

And my exact copy does NOT slide the address bar once loaded - open these links below on iPhone to see.

[HTML 5 BOILERPLATE](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile) - This hides address bar

[HTML 5 BOLIERPLATE MYSERVER](http://motocomdigital.co.uk/development/html5/boilerplate/) - Exact copy on my server but does not hide address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper.js file which contains the Javascript to hide the address bar isn't loading.

It's being called towards the bottom of the HTML file.

Comment: I eventually worked it out, but I'm sure this will help others. Thanks